# Angular 1 component vs directive definition

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-components

I'm pretty new to node.js and I'm planning to migrate our angular 1 directives to components in order to make easier the transition to Angular 2.

So, my question is that I have some code working with a couple of definitions like this:

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

angular.module('dashboard')
.directive('yepNope', require('./yep-nope.directive'))
//.component('comp', require('./myFirstComponent.component'));
.component('comp', new (require('./myFirstComponent.component')));
```

Both yep-nope.directive and MyFirstComponent.component are defined in the same way:

```
'use strict';

function MyFirstComponent() {

    function componentController($element){
        var vm = this;

        init();

        function init(){
            vm.api = {
                bar : function(){
                    console.log('bar called');                            
                },
                foo :  function(){
                    console.log('foo called');                            
                }
            };                        
        }

        this.$onInit = function(){
            console.log("$onInit");
        };

        this.$postLink = function(){
            console.log("$postLink");                    
        };

        this.$onChanges = function(changesObj){
            console.log("$onChanges");
        };
    }

    return {
        bindings: { },
        controller: componentController,
        //controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template:'<div><h1>My Component header</h1></div>'
    }
}

module.exports = MyFirstComponent;
```

and

```
'use strict';

function YepNopeDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.check, function (val) {
        var words = val ? 'Yep' : 'Nope';
        element.text(words);
      });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = YepNopeDirective;
```

Is there any explanation why defining the component I need to do a new(require... while with a directive this is not needed?

```
.directive('yepNope', require('./yep-nope.directive'))
//.component('comp', require('./myFirstComponent.component'));
.component('comp', new (require('./myFirstComponent.component')));
```

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

Component are defined in the a different way that traditional directives. While directives require a function, components require a object of options:

```
app.directive(name, fn)
app.component(name, options)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need require at all:

```
.directive('yepNope', YepNopeDirective);
```

If you do need require, You might need to review your project architecture.

You don't convert a directive to a component.

You convert your application to a component architecture using `.component` but [directives stay directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#make-a-structural-directive)

Comment: Forget about this simple example. The directives is our project are not Angular 2 compatible (we use compile and replace among others). In that position, it is worth it for us to convert directives to components.

Anyways, my question is why I need to do a new(require when using a component when with a directive I don't have to.